# Android onclick Login Crash

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I'm new Android developer - I'm trying to implement an `onClickListener`, so that when a button is clicked, it checks the text entered, and if it's right, starts a new activity.

There are no errors displayed in either the XML file or class. But when the text fields matchs the code, the application crashes. [ In LogCat, in line: `startActivity(intent)`; ]

If you can that, that would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public class HomeMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText editTextUN;
    EditText editTextPW;
    Button buttonlogin;
    Button buttoncancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_main);

        editTextUN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUN);
        editTextPW = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPW);
        buttonlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
        buttoncancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncancel);

        buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; 
        // this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String un=editTextUN.getText().toString();
        String pw=editTextPW.getText().toString();
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonlogin:
                if(un.equals("techie") && pw.equals("techie")) {
                    Intent x=new Intent(this,Menu.class);
                    startActivity(x);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttoncancel:
                editTextUN.setText("");
                editTextPW.setText("");
                break;
            default: break;
            }
    }
}
```

This is my other class that the onClick should go to. (Nothing really happens in here yet. For now its just another screen)

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

And also, the LogCat error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1702): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.appname.appname/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.appname.appname.HomeMain.onClick(HomeMain.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

And this is the Manifest below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appname.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.HomeMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.Admin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.NewJob"
        android:label="@string/add_new_job" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.EditJob"
        android:label="@string/edit_job" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.Scroll"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scroll" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.AddNewJob"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_new_job" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.appname.appname.HomeMain"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_main" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appname.appname.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Have you added the Menu activity to your manifest?

Comment: Are the buttons declared in activity_home_main.xml?

Comment: LogCat posted now. The Menu activity is in my manifest. The buttons are declared in the XML

Comment: Are you declaring the name as ".Menu"? If so, replace with the full package path. It is not recognizing the activity in your manifest.

Comment: The package name in manifest for Menu activity , seems to be wrong. Its referring to Menu View

Comment: You declare HomeMain twice. Remove the second one.

Comment: Is it worth it to refactor Menu to something like MenuScreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a collision between your activity `Menu` and the actual `view.Menu`.

Instead of calling `Menu.class` do `com.appname.appname.Menu.class`

```
Intent x = new Intent(this, com.appname.appname.Menu.class);
startActivity(x);
```

Or rename your activity.

Comment: @user3577160 No problem! Just to let you know, since you're new, you can mark the answer as accepted instead of mentioning it worked in a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to fix in the code you show here. Based on the LogCat, your application crashes upon performing the startActivity(). The problem lies in running your other activity. If you also post Menu.java and the full LogCat Message, then someone could help you in debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the `Menu Activity` in `Manifest`

Add this.

```
<activity android:name="com.appname.appname.Menu"/>
```

Change the package name if different.

Answer (score 0):

First Remove extra activity declaration from the `Manifest`

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.appname.appname.HomeMain"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_home_main" >
</activity>
```

To fix this error change this line

`Intent x=new Intent(this,Menu.class);`

to

`Intent x=new Intent(this,com.appname.appname.Menu.class);`

Your `HomeMain` activity already has `import android.view.Menu;`